# What is the most elegant way to extract an value from a database

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, select

I am trying to get a Value from the SQlite database. I know that there is only 
that one value. When retrieving it via SELECT, it returns a list, which also contains the key of the row.
I just want to get the value, which is an int.

What is the most elegant/best solution to this problem?

I was thinking about getting the list via SELECT, remove all non-numerical chars and turn it into an int.

the return value (data = ) is [{'cash': 10000}]. I just want to extract the 10000.

```
data base (example)

id || username || hash || cash
1 || user1 || xxx || 10000
2 || user2 || yyy || 5400

data = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :userid",userid=session.get("user_id"))
currentCash = str(data[0])
userCurrentCash = re.sub("[^0-9]","",currentCash)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you normally use `execute` on a cursor object and then one of the `fetchFOO` methods?

Comment: @Shawn how does it differ, when using a cursor object and use the fetchxx methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `data` returns `[{'cash': 10000}]`, `data[0]['cash']` will return `10000`. It will be (automatically) cast as an integer.